# SQL-Case / Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my code, which I'm trying to get working:

```
DECLARE @DATE AS SMALLDATETIME ,
    @BasTar DATE ,
    @Bittar DATE 

SET @DATE = GETDATE() - 1
SET @BasTar = GETDATE() - 1
SET @Bittar = GETDATE() - 1


SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.DEFAULT_RETURN_PRICE )
                   END), 0) AS SATIST ,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.VAT_TOTAL )
                   END), 0) AS SATISIV ,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 2, 6 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.DEFAULT_RETURN_PRICE )
                   END), 0) AS IADET ,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 2, 6 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.VAT_TOTAL )
                   END), 0) AS IADEIV ,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                             AND TH.STATUS = 0 THEN TS.AMOUNT
                   END), 0) AS SATISMIK ,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 2, 6 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                             AND TH.STATUS = 0 THEN TS.AMOUNT
                   END), 0) AS IADEMIK
FROM    TRANSACTION_HEADER TH WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_SALE TS WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON TS.FK_TRANSACTION_HEADER = TH.ID
        INNER JOIN STORE ST WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ST.ID = TH.FK_STORE
                                               AND ST.NUM BETWEEN '3999' AND '9999'
WHERE   TH.STATUS = 0
        AND ST.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'POL_%'
        AND ST.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'SIS%'
        AND CONVERT(CHAR(11), TH.TRANS_DATE, 103) BETWEEN @BasTar
                                                  AND     @Bittar
```

So because I use `ST.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR)` in the case statement, it gives me that error for each sum(case) statement.

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: The problem is you have a subquery inside a SUM (this is the aggregate mentioned) which is prevented as part of the SQL specification, so this won't work. Not sure what you're trying to achieve though so difficult to suggest an alternative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, and I don't have your schema so I can't test this, but you might be able to move the SUMming out of the main query, here's an example using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx);

```
DECLARE @DATE AS SMALLDATETIME ,
    @BasTar DATE ,
    @Bittar DATE 

SET @DATE = GETDATE() - 1
SET @BasTar = GETDATE() - 1
SET @Bittar = GETDATE() - 1

; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  ISNULL(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.DEFAULT_RETURN_PRICE )
                   END, 0) AS SATIST ,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.VAT_TOTAL )
                   END, 0) AS SATISIV ,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 2, 6 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.DEFAULT_RETURN_PRICE )
                   END, 0) AS IADET ,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 2, 6 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                        THEN ( TS.VAT_TOTAL )
                   END, 0) AS IADEIV ,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                             AND TH.STATUS = 0 THEN TS.AMOUNT
                   END, 0) AS SATISMIK ,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN TH.PTYPE IN ( 2, 6 )
                             AND ST.ID IN ( SELECT  ID
                                            FROM    FLO_AA_MAGAZALAR )
                             AND TH.STATUS = 0 THEN TS.AMOUNT
                   END, 0) AS IADEMIK
FROM    TRANSACTION_HEADER TH WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_SALE TS WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON TS.FK_TRANSACTION_HEADER = TH.ID
        INNER JOIN STORE ST WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ST.ID = TH.FK_STORE
                                               AND ST.NUM BETWEEN '3999' AND '9999'
WHERE   TH.STATUS = 0
        AND ST.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'POL_%'
        AND ST.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE 'SIS%'
        AND CONVERT(CHAR(11), TH.TRANS_DATE, 103) BETWEEN @BasTar
                                                  AND     @Bittar
)
SELECT
    SUM(SATIST) AS SATIST,
    SUM(SATISIV) AS SATISIV,
    SUM(IADET) AS IADET,
    SUM(IADEIV) AS IADEIV,
    SUM(SATISMIK) AS SATISMIK,
    SUM(IADEMIK) AS IADEMIK
FROM
    CTE
```